# Frame-Duplicated Metaballs not rendering in Blender 2.79

Tags: bezier-curves, dupli-groups, meta-objects

I am trying to create a flow of water by duplicating metaballs along a curve. I've gone through the motions of creating a curve and a metaball, setting the `Parent` of the metaball to the curve, set the `Duplication` to `Frames`, unchecking `Speed`, and animated the `End` frame. Looks good in the viewport (sometimes needing to click the `Update` buttons to get it to update).

However, when I go into Rendered view or actually rendering the thing, none of the metaballs show up, not even the starting metaball. Changing `Duplication` to `None` shows the whole thing in Rendered View, but when I do anything to update the metaballs I only get the starting metaball. I even played around with the metaball's resolutions to no effect.

Is there any other method to create this growing "sausage"? Remember the material is semi-transparent so using ordinary spheres will produce ugly overlaps.

[image]

Comment: Simple plane with array modifier along curve and dupliface option can be used instead of your current setup. As for sphere overlaps - this can be eliminated inside shader, forcing all transparent bounces greater than 1 to be fully transparent (downside of this method is having a big number for transparency max bounds to reduce black artifacts).

Comment: @SergeL I'm not getting the desired result, or I'm just misinterpreting that first part. Maybe make a full answer (tutorial) what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's a bug or not, but if you <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> duplicate metaball on the same layer, dupliframed metaballs start rendering fine. To hide this copied metaball, clear relation to parent object (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and put it outside view area or parent to camera and move behind it.

[image]

Comment: Very odd. Your blend file seems to work, but when I try the steps you suggested, it did not work.

Comment: Maybe share your file?